# Search by best values for every minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

The problem I'm having is that I have a table of data that has a new row added every second (imagine the structure {id, timestamp(datetime), value}). I would like to do a single query for MSSQL to go through the table and output only the number of objects that have the top 2 values asc for each minute ( also output ).

Any ideas please?

Sample data:

```
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00  128
2   2015-01-01 00:00:01  128
3   2015-01-01 00:00:04  129
4   2015-01-01 00:00:05  123
...
67  2015-01-01 00:00:59  128


Output : 

starttime  endtime  number
2015-01-01 00:00:00  2015-01-01 00:00:59  4
```

Comment: SELECT MAX(value), datetime
FROM table
GROUP BY DATEPART

Something like this? However I do not know if it is possible for a datepart to be minute. But I'm sure you can find something if you search for 'group by minute'. Keep in mind though this would only give you the highest value for every minute.

Comment: What does "best" mean? And how does the output become `4`? What happened to the `2015-01-01 00:01:00` minute?

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry, had to edit my post to clarify the idea: best refer to top values asc, 4 is the number of objects related to the top values which are 129 and 128 in this example.

Comment: Use `row_number` with `value` for order by and `DateDiff` for the partitioning. select where row_number <= 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [@ZoharPeled in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002301/search-by-best-values-for-every-minute/70003041#comment123745622_70002301), you can use `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` to partition by minute. Then use `DENSE_RANK` to take the top two `value` results.

```
SELECT
  t.StartTime,
  EndTime = DATEADD(second, 59, t.StartTime),
  number = COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY v.StartTime ORDER BY t.value DESC)
    FROM YourTable t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
        DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, '20000101', t.timestamp), '20000101')
    )) v(StartTime)
) t
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY
  t.StartTime;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc5649374c15b5e28f9f0a53b015298f)

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to do this is to trim the date down to the minutes then stick that in a temp table and then select max(value), [date stripped down to the minute] from temptable group by [date stripped down to the minute].

This is a simple way of doing it and as you are asking this I assume you want an easy to understand solution.